# Python pyautogui bot works for some time and then TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object Solution

Tags: python, bots, pyautogui

```
    from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

time.sleep(3)


def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)



while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('archer.png', confidence=0.8, region=(260, 760, 1400, 200)) is not None:
        width, high, g, b = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('archer.png', confidence=0.8, region=(260, 760, 1400, 200))`    `
        click(width, high)
```

Any one knows why and what should i do to prevent this TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object Solution

Comment: Note that pyautogui has a [click function](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks) that you could use in place of yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `locateOnScreen` a second time, it is returning a none object because of not locating your template image `'archer.png'`.

This could be caused by the screen state changing since your first call in every iteration of the while loop. Calling `locateOnScreen` only once as shown below should fix the error but since your screen state seems to be changing, whatever you want to click on the screen might disappear before the mouse moves to the identified location.

```py
while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    imageBox = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('archer.png', confidence=0.8, region=(260, 760, 1400, 200)) 
    # imageBox is none if archer.png is not located
    # otherwise, it is a four-tuple representing the left coordinate, top coordinate,
    # width and height of a box surrounding the location of archer.png
    if imageBox is not None:
        click(imageBox[0], imageBox[1])
```