# Trying to find a colour and click on it in python

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am a beggineer in python and I am interested in automation, (keyboard and mouse movements!) And to try something new with pyautogui I wanted to see if I can see an image or colour and then click on it. To do this i thought an offline game might be good since i can do it in my own time and it would be a fun project.

button = "Playagain.png"
pyautogui.doubleClick(button)

I tried to use a variable and the double click function in pyautogui but that did not work. and I tried to see if i could grab the colour of the button but that is diffucult and i didn't understand that. So if anyone could help me that would be very good!

Some extra bits of infomation might be. The Play again button is allways in the same place but it comes up at diffrent times. It might come up at 10 seconds or 30 seconds and that's why i wanted to use image or colour recognition because it would be 100x more efficient

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your example did not work because `pyautogui.doubleclick` takes screen coordinates as inputs. You need to use [locate functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions) to locate an image on screen and then pass the coordinates of the detected image to `doubleclick` . This is an example from the docs:

```py
import pyautogui
x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('image.png')
pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

Comment: Hey thank you go the suggestion, i tried what you said and this is what it looks like now:

button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Playagain.png')
pyautogui.click(button)

But it does not seem to be working

Comment: Is your mouse moving to the expected location `pyautogui.moveTo(button)`? Locate function returns None if the image is not detected. So you can check if `button` is None or a tuple of valid coordinates

Comment: The mouse does not move at all sadly.

Comment: Looks like your `button` variable is `None`. If so, the image is not being detected, which could mean it is not on the screen

Comment: I do have 2 moniters, Do you recomend i switch the game to the other moniter? could that be the issue

Comment: Also do you mind expanding on waht you mean by "None" Sorry I didn't understand I am a begginer after all

Comment: You can try switching monitors, just note that [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#faq-frequently-asked-questions) locates an image only if it is on the primary monitor. Also, your question seems to indicate that the button appears/disappears from the screen intermittently. If you run locateCenterOnScreen when the button is not on screen, it will return a None object instead of the xy coordinates because it cannot detect the image.

Comment: None is a python object. If you want a variable to not point to any value, you can assign None to it like variable= None. If you do `print( variableName is None )` , it will print True if your variable is pointing to the None object

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68584121/14409072) shows how to keep image detection continuously running until you press 'q'. Just note that you need to install the keyboard module and do `import keyboard` first

Comment: I see, thank you for the infomation on variables. In the game, the play again button appears randomly from anywhere from 15-45 seconds once it does show up my cursor does not go over there to click it which is my issue at the moment. Does it matter if the button is slightly transparrent because the button is very slightly transparrent

Comment: It should not matter if 'Playagain.png' has the same transparency (& resolution- pixel size) as the button. If not, I suggest screenshotting the button when it appears and saving it as 'Playagain.png'. To detect the button when it appears, you need to keep locateCenterOnScreen running continuously in a while loop (as shown in the answer I linked above) instead of running it just once. Or at the least you will have to run locateCenterOnScreen only when you know that the button is displayed on the screen

Comment: ```
while True:

    button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Playagain.png')
    pyautogui.click(button)

    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        break
```

This is a small snippet of my code to click on the play again button but it still does not work, Can you see any errorrs?

Comment: This looks good. To test you code, I suggest replacing pyautogui.click(button) with if button is not None: print('Button detected') pyautogui.moveTo(button) to check whether the button is being detected and whether the mouse is moving to the location of the button

Comment: For the if statment would i just do !=? since i am not to sure with all the equles and exlamation points

Comment: Yes `if button != None:` should work since != is the "not equal to" operator. `if not button is None:` will also work

Comment: I have done what you have said and it did not say the button was decected so that must mean it can't see the button.

Comment: Try replacing `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Playagain.png')` with `pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Playagain.png', confidence=0.8)`. This has a confidence parameter that you can tune between 0 and 1 to see if you can achieve detection. Also, I recommend saving 'Playagain.png' by screenshotting the button when it appears on screen instead of using an icon saved from some other place because it can have a different size (in pixels) than how it is displayed on screen

Comment: I have taken of the image from my own pc and it is now saying the button is being dectected but it is clicking places completly unrelated

Comment: Try increasing confidence gradually till you can detect only the button. Also you will need to do `button= pyautogui.center(button)` right after `if button !=None:` because `locateOnScreen` returns the coordinates of a box surrounding the detected image instead of its center

Comment: while True:

    button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Playagain.png', confidence=0.1)
    if button != None:
        pydirectinput.center(button)
        print("Button Decected")
        pydirectinput.moveTo(button)

This is the code to click on the button but it still not working at 10%

Comment: while True: button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Playagain.png', confidence=0.1) if button != None: button = pyautogui.center(button) print("Button Decected") pyautogui.moveTo(button)

It should be this. You need to use locateOnScreen instead of locateCenterOnScreen when using the confidence parameter. Also, it is `button= pyautogui.center(button)` instead of `pyautogui.center(button)`

Comment: My code now looks like while True:

    button = pydirectinput.locateOnScreen('Playagain.png', confidence=0.1)
    if button != None:
        button= pydirectinput.center(button)
        print("Button Decected")
        pydirectinput.moveTo(button)

But it still seems to not work. Sorry for not understanding

Comment: You can use the exact code that worked earlier and gradually increase the threshold. If I remember correctly, it was based on pyautogui instead of pydirectinput. The only difference from that working code I suggested is this line `button= pyautogui.center(button)`. This line will change the detected button coordinates. It will not change the detection ability

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui

color = (75, 219, 106)

def clicker():
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        pixelColor = pyautogui.screenshot().getpixel((x, y))
        if pixelColor == color:
            pyautogui.click()

def main():
    while True:
        clicker()

main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).