# Pyautogui Image non-iterable after working for a while, TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, pyautogui

python 3.9.7
pyautogui 0.9.53

Having it look for images then moveRel and click but it's doesn't find the image it returns non-iterable

I have done to make sure it's finding the image

```
  while 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ScheduledBy.png', confidence=0.8) is not None:
                    print("Found")
            else:
                    print("Nope")
```

I'm able to find them just fine without false results

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random  
import win32api, win32con
def FindContact1():

    pyautogui.click(319,25)
    pyautogui.click(99,161)
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ScheduledBy.png', confidence=0.8) is not None:
            pyautogui.moveTo('ScheduledBy.png')
            pyautogui.moveRel(245,20)
            time.sleep(.1)
            pyautogui.click()
            time.sleep(.75)
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Email.png', confidence=0.8) is not None:
            pyautogui.moveTo('Email.png')
            pyautogui.moveRel(0,20)
            time.sleep(.2)
            pyautogui.tripleClick()
            time.sleep(.1)
            pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
            time.sleep(.1)
            pyautogui.click(88,25)
            time.sleep(.5)
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Cced.png', confidence=0.8) is not None:
            pyautogui.moveTo('Cced.png')
            pyautogui.moveRel(-44,0)
            time.sleep(.1)
            pyautogui.click()
            pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

Log:

```
  File "C:\Users\CDoz\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\Python\One Exhibit Request\One Exhibit Request\FindSheduledBy.py", line 175, in Contacts
    FindContact1()
  File "C:\Users\CDoz\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\Python\One Exhibit Request\One Exhibit Request\FindSheduledBy.py", line 135, in FindContact1
    pyautogui.moveTo('Cced.png')
  File "C:\Users\CDoz\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 598, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CDoz\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 1280, in moveTo
    x, y = _normalizeXYArgs(x, y)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
>>>
```

I tried this solution based on other posts that looked for images, but either I didn't do it right or it didn't work

Post :[Python pyautogui bot works for some time and then TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576560/python-pyautogui-bot-works-for-some-time-and-then-typeerror-cannot-unpack-non-i)
Post: [PyAutoGui TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70442076/pyautogui-typeerror-cannot-unpack-non-iterable-nonetype-object)

```
def FindContact1():
        ScheduledBy = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ScheduledBy.png', confidence=0.8)
        Email = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Email.png', confidence=0.8)
        Cced = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Cced.png', confidence=0.8)
        pyautogui.click(319,25)
        pyautogui.click(99,161)
        if ScheduledBy is not None:
                pyautogui.moveTo('ScheduledBy.png')
                pyautogui.moveRel(245,20)
                time.sleep(.1)
                pyautogui.click()
                time.sleep(.75)
        if Email is not None:
                pyautogui.moveTo('Email.png')
                pyautogui.moveRel(0,20)
                time.sleep(.2)
                pyautogui.tripleClick()
                time.sleep(.1)
                pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
                time.sleep(.1)
                pyautogui.click(88,25)
                time.sleep(.5)
        if Cced is not None:
                pyautogui.moveTo('Cced.png')
                pyautogui.moveRel(-44,0)
                time.sleep(.1)
                pyautogui.click()
                pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

I can make any small changes to it and it will start working again and stop working after a day.

```
def FindContact1():
        ScheduledBy = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ScheduledBy.png', confidence=0.8)
        Email = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Email.png', confidence=0.8)
        Cced = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Cced.png', confidence=0.8)
        pyautogui.click(319,25)
        pyautogui.click(99,161)
        time.sleep(1)
        if ScheduledBy is not None:
                print('Found Scheduled')
                pyautogui.moveTo('ScheduledBy.png')
                pyautogui.moveRel(245,20)
                time.sleep(.1)
                pyautogui.click()
                time.sleep(2)
                if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Email.png', confidence=0.8) is not None:
                        print("Found Email")
                        pyautogui.moveTo('Email.png')
                        pyautogui.moveRel(0,20)
                        time.sleep(.2)
                        pyautogui.tripleClick()
                        time.sleep(.1)
                        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
                        time.sleep(.1)
                        pyautogui.click(88,25)
                        time.sleep(2)
                        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Cced.png', confidence=0.8) is not None:
                                print("Found CCed")
                                pyautogui.moveTo('Cced.png')
                                pyautogui.moveRel(-44,0)
                                time.sleep(.1)
                                pyautogui.click()
                                pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def FindContact1():
        pyautogui.click(319,25)
        pyautogui.click(99,161)
        time.sleep(1)
        ScheduledBy = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('ScheduledBy.png', confidence=0.8)
        if ScheduledBy is not None:
                print("Found Scheduled")
                print(ScheduledBy[0], ScheduledBy[1])
                #print(ScheduledA[0], ScheduledA[1], ScheduledA[2], ScheduledA[3])
                pyautogui.moveTo(ScheduledBy[0], ScheduledBy[1])
                pyautogui.moveRel(245,20)
                time.sleep(.1)
                pyautogui.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                Email = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Email.png', confidence=0.8)
                if Email is not None:
                        print("Found Email")
                        print(Email[0], Email[1])
                        pyautogui.moveTo(Email[0], Email[1])
                        pyautogui.moveRel(-44,10)
                        time.sleep(.2)
                        pyautogui.tripleClick()
                        time.sleep(.1)
                        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
                        time.sleep(.1)
                        pyautogui.click(88,25)
                        time.sleep(1)
                        Cced = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Cced.png', confidence=0.8)
                        if Cced is not None:
                                print("Found CCed")
                                print(Cced[0], Cced[1])
                                pyautogui.moveTo(Cced[0], Cced[1])
                                pyautogui.moveRel(-44,0)
                                time.sleep(.1)
                                pyautogui.click()
                                pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

This post actually had the answer I just didn't understand it.

[Python pyautogui bot works for some time and then TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576560/python-pyautogui-bot-works-for-some-time-and-then-typeerror-cannot-unpack-non-i)

I'll try and explain how I solved it, but I'm new to coding so correct me if I'm wrong.

The `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` produces an output of `x,y,w,h` and the `pyautogui.moveTo` would only accept `x,y`

Two solutions are

You can just use `locateCenterOnScreen` as it will only produce `x,y`

or

Define the image

```
ScheduledBy = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('ScheduledBy.png', confidence=0.8)
```

You can use `locateCenterOnScreen` or `locateOnScreen`

then when you do `pyautogui.moveTo(ScheduledBy[0], ScheduledBy[1])`

the `[0],[1]` will grab the first two outputs of `locateOnScreen` & `locateCenterOnScreen`

`locateOnScreen` will have `x,y,w,h` `[0],[1],[2],[3]`

I hope this helps someone.